# ModX if inarray срабатывает каждый раз

Tags: modx

Пытаюсь сделать в чанке такую конструкцию (wayfinder)

```
[[If?
    &subject=`[+id+]`
    &operator=`inarray`
    &operand=`12,163,164`
    &then=`тут что-то`
    &else=`что-то другое`
]]
```

Но почему-то срабатывает каждый раз

Comment: Укажите, пожалуйста, версию Modx.

Comment: MODX Evolution 1.2-d9.0.4